# Relative Layout not showing when RecyclerView is not empty

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a firebaseRecyclerAdapter and I'm trying to hide a relative Layout if the recyclerview is empty. The problem is that the relative layout is gone but when I add items into the recycler view it doesn't show again. I've tried multiple things and can't get it to work.

```
mModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        mDairyDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ListFragment").child("Dairy");
        Query query = mDairyDatabase;
        mDairyDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if(value != null){
                    String name = value.get("Name");
                    String key = value.get("Key");
                    mModelList.add(new Model(name, key));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

//skipping random code

mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mDairyAdapter);
    mDairyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//random code again

relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.Dairy_RelativeLayout);
if (mDairyAdapter.getItemCount() == 0){
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

This is what I wrote in my InOnCreateView in my fragment. Also I tried `notifyDataSetChange` when the item is added the view still wouldn't return.

Comment: onCreate is not the appropriate place to check set views state, you should do that in onCreateView instead. Also can you put the code where you add items in the adapter, when you add items you always need to set visibility to gone, when you remove items you need to check the items count and see if you need to show the layout or not

Comment: I'm sorry I did mean OnCreateView and I thought I wouldn't even need to check Item count because it's a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter which automatically listens for changes.@AntonMakov

Comment: I think this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914759/android-firebase-database-adding-items-with-keys-to-recycler-view

Comment: I think your problem is with callback methods. `mDairyAdapter.getItemCount()` is called before `onChildAdded` so condition in `if` statement is always executed before data is retrieved from database.

Comment: @Yupi how do I solve this issue?

Comment: @Kristofer try to make checking inside `onChildAdded` for example `if(modelList.isEmpty) relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); else relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: @Yupi I tried doing that but the view didnt disappear after the adpater was empty